# Can a VAO name be re-used after calling glDeleteVertexArrays by calling glGenVertexArrays later?

Tags: c++, opengl

It is my understanding from the OpenGL documentation that a VAO can be deleted (glDeleteVertexArrays), and then later regenerated (glGenVertexArrays). However, I have an issue when I am getting an OpenGL error when trying to re-use an existing VAO variable in a Chunk class (for a Minecraft clone). This only happens for some chunks and I cannot understand why. I output the VAO value (unsigned int type) and it doesn't seem to change after deleting with glDeleteVertexArrays. It was my understanding from the documentation that this value would be reset to zero after running this function. See Chunk class code below.

```
void Chunk::load()
{
    // Update chunk state
    loaded = true;

    // Set up OpenGL buffers
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexVBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &textureVBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);
    
    // VAO bound before setting up buffer data
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    // Indices
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
                 indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), 
                 &indices[0], 
                 GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    // Vertices
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
                 vertices.size() * sizeof(float), 
                 &vertices[0], 
                 GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(unsigned int), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // Texture Coordinates
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, textureVBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
                 texCoords.size() * sizeof(float), 
                 &texCoords[0], 
                 GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    
    // Unbind
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

```
void Chunk::unload()
{
    // Update chunk state
    loaded = false;

    // Delete arrays/buffers.
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexVBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &textureVBO);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);
}
```

Comment: Which parts of the documentation states that the vao handle gets reset to zero when calling `glDeleteVertexArrays`? This is not the case. The vao is deleted, but the handle that you have is not touched. Where do you get the OpenGL error? And which error do you get?

Comment: @BDL I feared that I was misinterpreting the documentation in this aspect. I took "Once a vertex array object is deleted it has no contents and its name is again unused" as the VAO being set to zero. This led me to believe that I could call glGenVertexArrays again to generate a new handle for the VAO. If this is not the case, when I delete the VAO, how should I go about re-setting up the buffer data and VAO attributes? Do I need glGenVertexArrays as I have it or is this method not the correct way of thinking about this anyways? Thanks

Comment: @BDL I am getting invalid operation error. However I have not set up the error checking well to know exactly where.

Comment: You cannot generate a new handle for the VAO. You can generate a new VAO. You're code doesn't look wrong. You have to find out where exactly the problem is and then report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as `delete ptr;` in C++ or `free(ptr);` in C does not actually change the pointer value of `ptr` variable, calling `glDelete*` on an OpenGL object does not change the value of the variables you give it. It is up to you to not use the variable again or to assign it to a neutral value.

That having been said, if your intent is to immediately create a new VAO... why bother? Just clear out the old one by disabling all of the attribute arrays and buffer bindings, and its ready to be used anew:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

GLint maxAttrib;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS, &maxAttrib);

for(int attribIx = 0; attribIx < maxAttrib; ++attribIx)
{
  glDisableVertexAttribArray(attribIx);
  glVertexAttribPointer(attribIx, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, nullptr);
  glVertexAttribDivisor(attribIx, 0);
}
```

Comment: With this in mind, my method of regenerating the vertex array is incorrect, because the VAO already has a value from before. What I am now trying to figure out is how to effectively delete the VAO and VBOs, then regenerate them later. Is deleting the arrays and buffers then regenerating not a good way to do this?

Comment: @EvanRinehart: What does "regenerate" mean in this context? What happens between this "effectively delete" code and the "regenerate" code? Can't you just stop using it?

Comment: I am trying to accomplish a way of deleting vertex array and buffer data as different arrays and buffers are generated for various parts of the "world" in my program. If I generate the VAO once with glGenVertexArrays, and never delete it, the program seems to work fine. However what I don't want is memory to be used in the VAOs which should not be loaded at this time.

Comment: @EvanRinehart: VAOs don't really use memory; buffer objects do, but VAOs only store buffer object names, not their contents. I mean yes, they do have some storage, but it's on the order of bytes, not megabytes. And to be honest, you shouldn't have one VAO per object anyway; you should have one VAO per vertex *format* (the set of attributes and their associated interpretation). Buffer bindings should be ephemeral, not locked into place.

Comment: I now see your edit to your answer. This makes sense, as it frees up the storage space used by the VAO, while keeping the handle (insignificant memory usage). I am going to refactor later to combine chunk data to a single VAO and VBOs. Thanks for your help.